# Qt - debug dynamic library

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm working on a `Qt` application for `ARM` and using one of our own `Qt` library. Application compiles and runs fine. Now, I want to debug. I've this library source open in `Qt Creator` and compiled lib files are deployed at `/usr/lib` on target (`ARM` board). Setting up the break points in `Qt Creator` is not working i.e., debugger is never stopping at the breakpoints.

How to properly debug dynamically loaded libraries?

Answer (score 0):

You don't debug libraries, you debug processes. Attach to a process that runs on the target. If the process has loaded your library, your breakpoints will become active.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not clear. Isn't that what `Qt Creator` does? When you debug an application which is cross compiled, it starts remote `gdb-server` and then connects to it which effectively have loaded my library. This is where I'm getting lost. Thanks again.

Comment: Do you have an application, or just a library? `gdb-server` is there only to attach to a process - you need to have a process to attach to first. You say that you're debugging a library - that simply can't be done, a library has no entry point and doesn't run by itself.